# Get statistics from dates in one query (or in a fast way)

Tags: mysql

I have a table: `apns_devices` with columns: `estado, modified, pid, etc.` 
I want to get some statistics based on the last modified time i.e. modified last week, last month, yesterday, today and the total. Right now I'm doing one query (nested) for each period like:

```
SELECT t1.estado, t1.siempre, t2.hoy
FROM 
(SELECT *, COUNT(pid) as siempre FROM `apns_devices` GROUP BY estado) as t1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT *, COUNT(pid) as hoy   FROM `apns_devices` WHERE DATE (modified) = CURRENT_DATE GROUP BY estado) as t2 
ON t1.estado = t2.estado
```

*This is for today and the total*

In order to speed up the script; ¿How can I do this in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  estado,
  COUNT(*) siempre,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(modified) = CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS ModifiedToday,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), modified) = 1 THEN 1 END) AS ModifiedYesterday,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), modified) BETWEEN 2 AND 7 THEN 1 END) AS ModifiedLastWeek,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), modified) BETWEEN 8 AND 30 THEN 1 END) AS ModifiedYesterMonth
FROM
  apns_devices
GROUP BY
  estado
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f9e4/1).

Comment: Elegant and fast, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
    SELECT distinct estado,  
(SELECT COUNT(pid) as hoy   FROM `apns_devices` WHERE estado = a.estado and DATE (modified) = CURRENT_DATE) AS ModifiedToday, 
(SELECT COUNT(pid) as hoy   FROM `apns_devices` WHERE estado = a.estado and CURRENT_DATE - DATE (modified) = 1) AS ModifiedYesterday, 
(SELECT COUNT(pid) as hoy   FROM `apns_devices` WHERE estado = a.estado and CURRENT_DATE - DATE (modified) BETWEEN 2 AND 8) AS ModifiedLastWeek, 
(SELECT COUNT(pid) as hoy   FROM `apns_devices` WHERE estado = a.estado and CURRENT_DATE - DATE (modified) BETWEEN 9 AND 30) AS ModifiedLastMonth 
FROM apns_devices a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks nice, unfortunately with your code, I'm not getting the results `GROUPED BY estado`, `estado` is an `int` column which defines the *owner* of the row. So I want to get the statistics by *owner*.